# Extreme value theorem for $\frac{e^{\sin(x)} \sin(x)}{e^{x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Show that there exists an $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $$\frac{e^{\sin(x)} \sin(x)}{e^{x^2}} \leqslant \frac{e^{\sin(a)} \sin(a)}{e^{a^2}}$$
>   holds true.

My approach was to find a closed interval and use the fact that the function is continuous in order to apply EVT.

Let $f(x) = \frac{e^{\sin(x)} \sin(x)}{e^{x^2}}$.

Now using the fact that $-1 \leqslant \sin(x) \leqslant1$ we get that,

$\frac{e^{\sin(x)} \sin(x)}{e^{x^2}} \leqslant \frac{e}{e^{x^2}}$.

Taking the limit of this we have

$\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{e}{e^{x^2}} = 0$

and also noting that $f(1) > 0$.

Now by definition $\exists K >1$ such that, $|f(x)| < f(1)$.

Applying EVT here we get that $\exists a \in [-K, K]$ such that, $f(x) < f(a)$.

Since $1 \in [-K, K]$ we have $f(x) < f(1) < f(a)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know if this is applicable? Also all feedback would be *very* appreciated.

Comment: Yes, any continuous function that goes to $0$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ attains its maximum and minimum. You should be careful about putting strict inequalities here (it is true in this case but we could have $a=1$ for example so it is not true for all such $f$ and strict inequality does not follow from EVT)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your argument is correct. Since the limit is zero in both directions, it most be arbitrarily close to zero beyond some point, including within $f(1)$ of it. So it's smaller than $f(1)$ on all but some finite interval, so it's max is in that finite interval, and therefore exists by EVT. For one thing, though, you need absolute value around your inequality to prove the limit is zero. I might also remark explicitly that you're using the fact that the exponential function (and it's absolute value) is monotonous. Note also this is easy to show with periodicity. In particular, let $x = 2\pi k + \varepsilon$ where $k$ is an integer and $\varepsilon \in [-\pi, \pi]$. Then $f(x) = f(\varepsilon ) \exp(-2\pi k (2 \pi k +2 \varepsilon)$. The argument of the exponential is a quadratic in $k$ with vertex at $k= -\varepsilon / 2 \pi$, which has absolute value less than or equal to .5. by symmetry, then, the argument of the exponential can never be smaller for a nonzero $k$ than it is for zero. Since $f$ takes positive values, it's maximum must be positive and therefore it's maximum cannot do better than having $k=0$ when written in the form above. Thus we cannot do better in the reals than we can on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Then we can again simply apply EVT and derive our result.

Comment: I didn't catch it the first time, but  @Maximilian has noted you do also use strict inequalities when they don't apply.